# Postfix Email Server Cannot Send Mail to icloud.com Accounts

Tags: email, security, postfix, icloud

I have a *nearly* fully-functional email server which plays nice with itself, gmail, protonmail, hotmail, yahoo, aol, [a college], [a smaller company], and AT&T.

The problem is `icloud.com`:

```
May  1 02:58:58 server-hostname postfix/submission/smtpd[19699]: 683915DDD01: client=unknown[my.home.ip.address], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=my-username
May  1 02:58:58 server-hostname postfix/cleanup[19708]: 683915DDD01: message-id=<g6nsxx7ofspx6ijbyx6nzabv7zfk7g5vhu6p32qhnrkatdst6i@k6m2oeumayht>
May  1 02:58:58 server-hostname postfix/qmgr[19301]: 683915DDD01: from=<my-username@my-domain.com>, size=4675, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  1 02:58:58 server-hostname postfix/smtp[19706]: 683915DDD01: lost connection with mx01.mail.icloud.com[17.56.9.29] while sending RCPT TO
May  1 02:58:59 server-hostname postfix/smtp[19706]: 683915DDD01: to=<recipient-name@icloud.com>, relay=mx01.mail.icloud.com[17.57.154.33]:25, delay=1.2, delays=0.31/0/0.43/0.43, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with mx01.mail.icloud.com[17.57.154.33] while sending RCPT TO)
```

(Obviously, private details have been replaced)

This happens for every address we've tested on my server (that is, two usernames, and three domain names), but we've already verified `icloud.com` doesn't happen to be down; we can get mail to it from a `gmail.com` address.

In case it isn't obvious from the services my server *does* get along with, I have DKIM, DMARC, SPF, and now rDNS set up.  Is there some other security/verification feature that `icloud`, of all things, requires above and beyond `gmail`?

Comment: I have struggled with icloud for years, and keep myself off all the blocklists as much as I can.  I have never got them to accept mail.  outlook and hotmail was a problem, however I found a delisting request tool http://aka.ms/ocsipsup  You must be logged into a hotmail.  If you ever find a solution like this for icloud please let me know

Comment: Didn't you see the answer and the OP's comments on it? ipcheck.proofpoint.com was the one for him

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your server's IP or domain ended up on some blacklist which Apple uses for protection.

Check your IP with https://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check and IP with the domain with https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx. If you're on one of these lists that'd probably be the reason.

---

While at it, keep in mind that sending emails for your domain with no good reputation and a personal server IP that also has no reputation and potentially on some blacklists might not be the best practice for good deliverablity.

You might want to use a service like Mailgun (has a free plan with decent usage) or the like to send the emails though them. See https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/faqs.html#why-not-just-use-sendmail-postfix-courier-imap and https://www.jamroom.net/brian/documentation/guides/1312/set-up-postfix-with-mailgun-for-reliable-e-mail-delivery.

Comment: I had checked the IP against both of those lists, and did so again, and found no listings (only a couple timed out).  I actually finally got a useful error from `icloud`; rather than dropping the connection like it has been doing, it actually told me I'm blocked because of an entry on another list.  I've requested to be removed from that list.

Comment: Why not write which list? It might help someone with this issue in the future.

Comment: Good call.  The list is <ipcheck.proofpoint.com>

Comment: @MCLooyverse it helped?